# Perl DBI alternative to LongReadLen

Tags: linux, perl, oracle

I'd like to know the most memory-efficient way to pull arbitrarily large data fields from an Oracle db with Perl DBI.  The method I know to use is to set the 'LongReadLen' attribute on the database handle to something sufficiently large.  However, my application needs to pull several thousand records, so doing this arbitarily is extremely memory inefficient.

The [doc](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#LongReadLen) suggests doing a query upfront to find the largest potential value, and setting that.

```
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = $dbh->selectrow_array(qq{
    SELECT MAX(OCTET_LENGTH(long_column_name))
    FROM table WHERE ...
});
$sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
    SELECT long_column_name, ... FROM table WHERE ...
});
```

However, this is still inefficient, since the outlying data is not representative of every record.  The largest values are in excess of a MB, but the average record is less than a KB. I want to be able to pull all of the informatoin (i.e., no truncation) while wasting as little memory on unused buffers as possible.

A method I've considered is to pull the data in chunks, say 50 records a time, and set LongReadLen against the max length of records of that chunk.   Another work around, which could, but doesn't have to, build on the chunk idea, would be to fork a child process, retrieve the data, and then kill the child (taking the wasted memory with it).  The most wonderful thing would be the ability to force-free the DBI buffers, but I don't think that's possible.

Has anyone addressed a similar problem with any success?  Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

Perl v5.8.8, DBI v1.52

To clarify: the memory inefficiency is coming from using 'LongReadLen' together with {ora_pers_lob => 1} in the prepare.  Using this code:

```
my $sql = "select myclob from my table where id = 68683";
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:$db", $user, $pass ) or croak $DBI::errstr;

print "before";
readline( *STDIN );

$dbh->{'LongReadLen'} = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql, {'ora_pers_lob' => 1} ) or croak $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute() or croak( 'Cant execute_query '. $dbh->errstr . ' sql: ' . $sql );
my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;

print "after";
readline( *STDIN );
```

Resident memory usage "before" is at 18MB and usage "after" is at 30MB.  This is unacceptable over a large number of queries.

Comment: did you think to do it in a "parallel" way ?!

Comment: What do you mean by "extremely memory inefficient"?  I believe any LongReadLen memory tax is _per statement handle_, not per row fetched.  (I.e., fetching a thousand records with LOBs is _not_ a thousandfold memory penalty.)  Indeed, measuring `DBD::Oracle` 1.36 with `Devel::Size` suggests that a LOB "fetch buffer" is only as big needed for the largest LOB fetched so far.  So, if holding a single large buffer is bothersome, perhaps you could simply ORDER BY LENGTHB(long_col) and let the DBI grow it as needed.

Comment: I updated the post with more details. I did not mention my use of ora_pers_lob; you're correct that LongReadLen, by itself, is not memory-hungry.  Using LongReadLen without {ora_pers_lob=>1} in the prepare was resulting in ORA-24812, which I just solved.  So I believe my question is answered--I can use LongReadLen now with the rest of the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are your columns with large data LOBs (CLOBs or BLOBs)? If so, you  don't need to use LongReadLen at all; DBD::Oracle provides a LOB streaming interface.

What you want to do is to [bind the param](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD::Oracle#bind_param) as type `ORA_CLOB` or `ORA_BLOB`, which will get you a "LOB locator" returned from the query, instead of tex. Then you use [ora_lob_read](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD::Oracle#Data_Interface_for_LOB_Locators) together with the LOB locator to get data. Here's an example of code that's worked for me:

```
sub read_lob {
  my ( $dbh, $clob ) = @_;

  my $BLOCK_SIZE = 16384;

  my $out;
  my $offset = 1;

  while ( my $data = $dbh->ora_lob_read( $clob, $offset, $BLOCK_SIZE ) ) {
    $out .= $data;
    $offset += $BLOCK_SIZE;
  }
  return $out;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the LOB-special API.  But won't `return $out` copy what might be a very large scalar?

Comment: Yes, but at least it's only used when needed. And of course, if it's possible to process the data in a streaming fashion, then you can just do that in place of `$out .= $data`.

Comment: Right.  If memory use is the concern, streaming to disk or some other processing would be a good approach.  (You could also return `\$out` to avoid the copy.)

Comment: This method results in "DBD::Oracle::db ora_lob_read failed: ORA-24812: character set conversion to or from UCS2 failed (DBD ERROR: OCILobRead)" when ora_lob_read is called.

Comment: Solved the ORA-24812 issue.  This method is much better, and does not suck up more and more memory over multiple queries.  Though, I have a suspicion that this is doing what fetch does when ora_pers_lob is 0, which I can do now that the ORA-24812 is fixed.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think of it in this way :

```
use Parallel::ForkManager
use strict;

# Max 50 processes for parallel data retrieving
my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(50);

# while loop goes here
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {

# do the fork
$pm->start and next;

#
# Data retreiving goes here
#

# do the exit in the child process
$pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

check [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.9/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm) in [CPAN](http://cpan.org) to know more.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  If I cannot solve my ORA-24812 issue, I'll probably take this route.